# Best approach to log filtered message body in Apache Camel

Tags: logging, apache-camel

Our message body (XML) contains sensitive information which we don't want to log. What is the best approach to log the filtered message body? I'm defining my routes with Java DSL and would like to use log DSL.

Thank you very much
YUsuf

Comment: Best way shall be to persist in a JMS queue or topic. Problem with log files is that , if they roll then you'll end up losing the messages.With a JMS topic you can easily browse the messages.

Comment: We need human readable log files. Besides that we are indexing our log files with splunk. So don't think jms is a good solution here.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to stick to CamelLogProcessor (because this processor is invoked under the hood of log DSL), then it is possible to write own custom ExchangeFormatter and inject it into logger. [Documentation](http://camel.apache.org/log.html) might be useful.

Although mentioned processor does nothing special (but usually is totally sufficient):

```
public boolean process(Exchange exchange, AsyncCallback callback) {
    if (log.shouldLog()) {
        log.log(formatter.format(exchange));
    }
    callback.done(true);
    return true;
}
```

In such a case it might be good idea to write your own processor and route to it instead to log schema (if you have to use pretty DSL then write own component but I don't think it's what you really are after). Provided you has decided to route to your own implementation of Processor then you can log whatever you want to log (for example omit sensitive information) in whatever the way you prefer.

Camel's generic processor for logging is generic :), so project specific implementation worked quite well for me in both cases: sensitive information or limiting logging time.